# Migrating ASP.NET web forms application: ASP.NET MVC or Angular?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, architecture

I need a suggestion: I currently have an ASP.NET web forms application (pretty large scale) with three tier architecture and ado.net for database communication.

Application structure is

```
Web > BLL > DAL > BO,
```

BLL for business logic and DAL for database interaction using ado.net (stored procedures).

There are other 4 apps connecting with BLL that make applications tightly coupled. Now I have to redesign one application so we decided to change underlying technology.

And I currently have few options:

1. Change front end layer and rewrite complete app to Angular and have API layer on BLL (most time consuming and complex solution I guess)
2. Change font end to ASP.NET MVC and directly call BLL from controller (we can reuse existing html mostly, but app will remain tightly couple and still monolithic)
3. Change front end to ASP.NET MVC and write API layer on BLL and connect controller to BLL via API (not a good idea to add an extra http request for every sever call client > controller (server) > API ( server).

Please suggest any alternative approach. Is this good option to rewrite complete complex application from ASP.NET MVC to Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ASPT.NET CORE WebAPP and one or more ASP.NET CORE Web API, REST, microservices,  so you don´t need to expose your services on the web and would be better to maintain it and for huge systems. Used of EF core, with CQRS pattern, is a very good choice within your WEB API so you can implement your BLL on it. Try to use to SOLID principles, mostly the D, dependency of inversion, that has already a built in IOC container so you apply the dependency of injection on it. Don´t forget to secure the system with authorization and authentication. OAuth 2 is a good way to go!

Comment: ASP.NET CORE Web API, REST, microservices, so you don´t need to expose your services on the web : so i have to add BLL reference within solution?

Comment: You will apply it to your Web API and not the WebAPP and through the Entity Framework and not ADO.NET, of course, if you want to.

Comment: No , Thats mean you need web app with service layer (That enable to call restfull api services) Thats all You client side app.

Other side (Services side) Use either web api or asp.net core webapi with n-layers as wish.

Comment: One more thing to add both project into one solution while developing , that will help you while coding and developing. After completed you can host your backend and frontend on different server as per scope of project.